# chroot "Accessing a corrupted shared library"

Tags: ubuntu, chroot

I tried to execute the following command and got "Accessing a corrupted shared library" error. How can I resolve this?

```
sudo chroot /home/jack/develop /bin/bash
chroot: failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: Accessing a corrupted shared library
```

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov If there was a corrupted system-level library then the user would get the same error message when logging in. I expect that the OP has a shared library somewhere under `/home/jack/develop` that is corrupt. I suggest finding all `.so` files in the directory tree and checking them out.

Comment: You're onto something. I've totally neglected the fact that they are trying to chroot into some home directory.

Comment: Hi, 邢庆杰! Welcome here :) Could you tell us which platform you are currently on, i.e., x86_64, or arm64? The output of `uname -a` might help us. And, could you also add the output of `sudo file /home/jack/develop/bin/bash` to your question? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all you guys who are trying to provide help.

I noticed that some of the lib files from the git pull down were corrupted. I reclone them and they are fine.

Comment: I use ldd /bin/bash to find the related so files, then use the readelf -h xx.so to check if it's corrupted. Finally I found the root cause.